# How to assign window name of a Win32 EDIT control without displaying the text?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-interface

I am currently working on dynamically creating a Win32 dialog based on a list of parameters requested by an external application. In other words, the user must provide some text/boolean responses which are sent as soon as OK is clicked.

Because the order and amount of EDIT and BUTTON controls may vary, I need a way to identify each one of them. The obvious solution—to my limited Win32 knowledge—is to use the *lpWindowName* parameter as an identifier when creating the dialog and later iterating through the controls checking this same parameter to deal with the input data accordingly.

However, this causes the issue that EDIT controls automatically display their window name, which causes aesthetic issues (I don't want the identifier displaying).

Could anyone give me some pointers as to the most proper way to identify window controls without displaying the identifier to the user?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: AFAIR there's a property you can use to configure the default display text.

Comment: If your id can be a numeric one, abuse the HMENU parameter from CreateWindow, eventually "oring" a true ID (say, low word) with your "id' (then, high word)

Comment: @manuell: that is not an abuse. Dialog controls are DESIGNED to be identified by numeric ID, and using the HMENU parameter is how those IDs are assigned. This is in the CreateWindow/Ex() documentation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know :-) "Abuse" in the sense, for example, of using some bits in the ID to store types of control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Win32 dialog controls are not identified by name but by numeric ID instead.  When you create a control using [`CreateWindow/Ex()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679%28VS.85%29.aspx), you can use the `hMenu` parameter to assign an ID to it:

> For a child window, hMenu specifies the child-window identifier, an integer value used by a dialog box control to notify its parent about events. The application determines the child-window identifier; it must be unique for all child windows with the same parent window.

If you create a dialog window using a dialog resource via [`CreateDialogIndirect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`CreateDialogParam()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645445%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you assign the IDs in the control definitions.

Either way, you can then use [`GetDlgItem()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the HWND of a specific control if you want to manipulate it directly, or use related functions like [`GetDlgItemText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`GetDlgItemInt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), etc (and their corresponding setter functions).